# Does cockroachdb support extensions?

Tags: postgresql, cockroachdb

I am wondering whether cockroachdb supports extensions such as time-scale and others?, because I have a project which requires a third party postgres extension in conjunction with cockroachdb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, CockroachDB does not support any PostgreSQL extensions. It may one day support features from some of the most popular extensions, but it is very unlikely that it will ever be possible to use arbitrary PostgreSQL extensions directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a scale-out SQL database that supports both PostgreSQL client API and its extensions, I would encourage you to take a look at [YugaByte DB](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/quick-start/). We are reusing the PostgreSQL codebase on top of our sharded replicated transactional layer, rather than building a SQL engine from scratch, and that will allow us to stay compatible with new PostgreSQL features as well as extensions.